# How to generate 3d temperature mapping with python

Tags: python, heatmap

i got a home work from my company to create a picture of heat map from many datalogger that place in a cold room. So i have a lot of information about temperature(celcious) and postion of datalogger . My question is how to plot heatmap by python like this picture[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jPvvv.jpg)

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!  This site isn't mean for "How do I do this?" questions.  If you've made an attempt and it's not working as intended, then we can help you with that.  Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for further information.

Comment: Funnily your example is a 2D projection of a 3D map which gives you absolutely no idea of the temperature at a given point in space.

Comment: @KlausD. I was thinking the same

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57461819/7919597